# Where is the welcome page set in a Maven webapp archetype project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, web.xml, maven-archetype

I created a Maven project with webapp archetype. There is just an index.jsp file in /src/main/webapp folder. The web.xml file doesn't mention any welcome file. No other mention or any setting elsewhere. On running the application, the index.jsp page is shown. Where is this page being set as welcome page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from https://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list

By default server looks for the welcome file in following order:

1) welcome-file-list in web.xml

2) index.html

3) index.htm

4) index.jsp

If none of these files are found, server renders 404 error.